Trying to sum monthly data by quarter and fill the value of each month with its quarter's value in R
I have a data table with month and passengers. I want to sum the number of passengers for all four months in a quarter. My 'flights_ts' data time series tibble starts in January.
Here is a sample time series tibble, very similar to my data:
flights_ts <- tsibble(Month = yearmonth(make_date(2003, 1) + months(0:24)), Passengers = c(1,5,7,9,3,5,6,7,7,2,5,9), index = Month)

And my code:
# Create a quarter column based on the month in the date
quarterly_ts <- flights_ts %>% mutate(quarter = rep(1:(n() %/% 4), each = 4, length.out = n()))

# Group by quarter and calculate the sum for each group
summary_ts <- quarterly_ts %>% group_by(quarter) %>% summarise_all(qtr_passengers = sum(Passengers))

head(summary_ts)

Any ideas?
Ideally, the output of the sample data would be 22 for each month in Jan 2003 - Apr 2003, 21 for May 2003 - August 2003, and 23 for September 2003 - December 2003.
When I run my code, it just reproduces the original data in the qtr_passengers column for each month. Any thoughts?

Please test your suggested code, as it doesn't run as currently provided. (e.g. you provide 25 months, and 12 Passengers.

Perhaps you mean something like "trimester" if you're referring to 4 month periods; if it were quarters each would have 3 months.

I'm going to assume you mean 3 month quarters, and I'll tweak the example data to what I presume you intended.
If you want 4 month periods (apparently those can be called "quadrimesters" but I've never seen that word before!), you'd adjust the %/% 3 to %/% 4 below.
flights_ts <- tsibble(Month = yearmonth(make_date(2003, 1) + months(0:23)), 
                      Passengers = rep(c(1,5,7,9,3,5,6,7,7,2,5,9), times =2), index = Month)


quarterly_ts <- flights_ts %>% 
  mutate(quarter = (lubridate::month(Month) -1) %/% 3 + 1,
         year = lubridate::year(Month))
    summary_ts <- quarterly_ts %>% 
  mutate(qtr_passengers = sum(Passengers), .by = c(quarter, year))

Note, .by was introduced in dplyr 1.1.0 in early 2023. I prefer it in most cases to group_by(some, variables) |> mutate(stuff) |> ungroup() since it's more concise, it limits the grouping to the current step, and doesn't change the order of your results without asking.
Note also, but using mutate in that last step, we keep all the original rows but with the addition of a by-group qtr_passengers calculation. If you want a single row per year-quadrimester, use summarize there instead of mutate.
